# Do you need a passport to take the ferry from France to Ireland?

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, ferries, ireland

As seen in the [Politics SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/28233/why-is-it-impossible-to-leave-the-single-market-without-a-hard-irish-border?noredirect=1#comment104941_28233):

> Right now, you can jump on a ferry in France, head over to Cork, drive up to Belfast and catch the ferry to Liverpool, without ever showing your passport to anyone. It seems inconceivable that this arrangement could be maintained if and when the UK leaves the EU.

Best I'm aware you'd need to show your passport before boarding in France, in much the same way that you do when taking the Eurostar to London. Because Ireland, like the UK, isn't part of the Schengen zone.

Which is it?

Bonus question: would you also need to show your passport to go from Belfast to Liverpool, or is that second assertion factual?

Comment: I was asked to produce ID on the TGV between Strasbourg and Paris last summer so it seems a good idea to carry some ID. I did not have my UK passport but in the end he accepted my German drivers license. When I traveled the same route last month there were no checks. So although there might not be standardised checks you might be asked to produce id at any time.

Comment: Arguably the assertion is technically correct, if when you 'jump on the ferry' in France you've necessarily already shown your passport (I can't remember which side passport checks are done France->Ireland).

Comment: @abligh It's done both when exiting France and when entering Ireland

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The Schengen area (of which France forms part) and Ireland are different countries for border purposes.

Therefore, you will need a passport (or national ID card from an EU/EFTA country) to exit France and enter Ireland - it will have to be presented to border control, and also stamped in the case of non-EU/EFTA passports.

Belfast to Liverpool is a domestic trip of course, so no fixed border control, but internal alien checks are not uncommon, so it'd be good to be able to prove you're not in the UK illegally.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74089/discussion-on-answer-by-coke-do-you-need-a-passport-to-take-the-ferry-from-franc).